# C# / GTK# Serial Port Read Issue

Tags: c#, gtk#

So I'm trying to read real time data from the serial port object in C# / Gtk#.  I have a product which talks over RF to the computer and every time it gets a command it sends back an ACK.  If I use AccessPort and auto send a command every 500ms, I get my ACK.  I've ran AccessPort for hours and been able to match every single command to an ACK, so I know this is physically working.

I wrote a small program in C# / Gtk# that send data out the serial port at X ms and has a delegated thread which reads the serial port for any bytes that come back.  My problem is that no matter how I write the method for the serial reading, it never actually captures all the bytes that I know are there.

So far this is the "lightest" code I have:

```
    private void readSerial(){
    byte readByte = 0x00;

    Gtk.Application.Invoke (delegate {
        try {
            readByte = (byte)serialPort.ReadByte();
            Console.WriteLine(readByte.ToString("X2"));
        } catch (System.ArgumentException sae) {
            Console.WriteLine(sae.Message);
        }
    });
}
```

I have assigned that method to a thread in the main function:

```
    writeThread = new Thread (writeSerial);
    readThread = new Thread (readSerial);
```

And I start it when a connect button is pressed, along with the writeThread.  The writeThread is working fine as I can see the product execute the correct instruction every X ms ( currently I'm testing at 500ms).  The ACK should arrive at the computer every X ms + 35 ms * module ID, so if my end product has a module id of 2 the response would be delayed by 70ms and hence the computer should see it at 570ms or X + 70ms.

Is there a better way to do this?  I'm I doing something boneheadedly wrong?

Some other code I've played with was reading 0x0E bytes from the serial port and storing the bytes into a buffer, this also missed a lot of the bytes I know are coming back.

Can anyone offer some help?  I do know the readSerial method is actually starting as I do see a 0x00 pop out on the console, which is correct as 0x00 are dispersed among the data I'm looking for.

Comment: What happens if you also catch and log other exceptions?

Comment: Good idea!  If I add a catch(System.Exception se) and do a Console.WriteLine(se.Message), I still don't see anything, but it was a good idea!

I also tried swapping out ReadByte() for ReadExisting() and then converting the string to a byte array and printing that with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

I'm not sure what the exact issue was but when I removed the delegation and just used a while(true) look inside that method it worked fine.